# XML - Java Error when using getChildNode

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to read a XML file with JAVA

Here is the XML sample

I want to get the information from a node child

```
'<segment_list>
  <segment id="01">
    <height>100</height>
    <slope>0</slope>
    <length>10 Km</length>
    <rrc>0.01</rrc>
    <max_velocity>90 Km/h</max_velocity>
    <min_velocity>0 Km/h</min_velocity>
    <number_vehicles>30</number_vehicles>
</segment>
  <segment id="02">
    <height>100</height>
    <slope>0.5%</slope>
    <length>5 Km</length>
    <rrc>0.01</rrc>
    <max_velocity>90 Km/h</max_velocity>
    <min_velocity>0 Km/h</min_velocity>
    <number_vehicles>20</number_vehicles>
  </segment>
</segment_list>'
```

And i want to retrieve the information from the 2 segments ... (Note there are more segments in the file, but they are splitted for another tab ... For this reason i really need to use the nodechild)

And in my java code what i'm trying to do is select the segment section and their child's , get the id and get all the attributs. But when i run the programa, i receive this type of messages: "#text , and #height ,and nullPoint

```
               NodeList listSegment = doc.getElementsByTagName("segment").item(0).getChildNodes();

                ListSegment listaSegment = new ListSegment();
                for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < listSegment.getLength(); temp1++) {

                    Node nodeSegment = listSegment.item(temp1);

                    if (nodeSegment.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                        Element eElement = (Element) nodeSegment;

                        System.out.println("Segment id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                        System.out.println("height : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("height").item(0).getTextContent().replaceAll("\"", ""));

                        //MORE PRINTS HERE....

                        System.out.println("number_vehicles : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("number_vehicles").item(0).getTextContent().trim());
                    }
                }
```

Sorry for the long post.

I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just:

begin to select  segment_list (I suppose only one)

```
    Node the_first=document.getElementsByTagName("segment_list").item(0);

    nodes = the_first.getElementsByTagName("segment");
```

listaSegment  is useless

or xpath, more powerfull, faster and works:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "//segment";
NodeList listSegment = (NodeList)  xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: I'm obliged to use just getAttribute, getElementsBytagName, get ChildNode ....

Before i made something like u did : 'nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("segment");' but when i run the program appears also the  segments that dont belong to the segment_list .. for that reason i guess i need to use getNodeCHild to print jsut that 2 segments, and when i call the other segment list appear just  segment that belong.

Comment: @Joseph  I modify my answer: begin to select segment_list

Comment: Worked ... I accepted the answer as an correct one ;)